# HTML TextArea - display special characters

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8

I'm having problems displaying this character on a *textarea*:

```
…
```

My web page (including meta header and file encoding) encoding is in UTF-8. The database, table and respective field are also in UTF-8, since it is the default encoding. I am working with European text.

I read the text saved in the database and display it on the textarea.

However this character (and only this character) keeps getting displayed as:

```
&
```

**How can I display this character correctly in a *textarea*?**

Should I change the encoding of my page/database to UTF-16 or something similar? Should I use a pre tag? Should I call some function such as htmlentities() with PHP (I already am!) to display the page?

I apologise in advance if I'm missing something obvious.

**Note #1:** Please note, the character is "…" (ellipsis) and NOT "..." (three dots);

**Note #2:** I am using webmin to manage the DB and it shows the data correctly. But interestingly, when I edit the row, the data is also displayed as "*&*" in the textarea from webmin.

**Note #3:** I did a print_r() of the data to display inside the textarea. When I inspect the HTML, everything shows fine, but the symbol "…" is getting displayed as

```
 & amp ;
```

(all together. I had to separate the chars to display it correctly here)

This is equivalent to "&". I am using

```
htmlspecialchars($string_for_textarea, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

To generate the HTML... I am currently trying to see why this function could be messing with the character...

Comment: what is the html of the rendered text area?

Comment: What are you typeing inside the textarea tag?

Comment: In the text area I display the text stored in the database. The HTML displayed is "&" (but in the database I see "…")

Comment: Show an actual sample of HTML as received by a browser. If it contains “…”, then the issue is with rendering, and we need to know the relevant CSS too. If not, then the problem is in generating te HTML.

Comment: You should also test with the generated test data placed e.g. in `p` element, to see whether this is in any way connected with `textarea` specifically.

Comment: Well, in webmin the same text is displayed correctly in a normal  HTML table, and also as "&" in a textarea... So I'm guessing this is also related to the textarea element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - the problem was elsewhere.

The data displayed in the textarea was actually imported from a spreadsheet using the PHP Excel Reader library.

For some reason, in the PHP script that imported the values, if a cell had this symbol, it would be read differently than a cell without it.

I changed to PHPExcel (another library) and managed to import these values correctly.

Thanks for all your feedback and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just copying it from somewhere and pasting it inside your source? if so, 
I suggest you use the ascii code of the ellipsis as follows

```
<textarea>&#133;</textarea>
```

Comment: No, I am reading it from the database (using MySQL and PHP) and displaying it in the textarea. The problem is, in the database I see "…" but when I render it in HTML it displays "&"

Comment: @user1183352 Can you do a var_dump of the data before you display it inside a text area and put it in your question?

Comment: @user1183352 I can write a workaround but I'm really looking into what's causing this. the & sign in "&#133;" gets escaped to &amp; which is killing the display of the ascii but that doesn't make sense of why it is removing #133 as well..

Comment: BTW—"…" isn't an ASCII character but it is a Unicode character, which is good because HTML4/5 numeric character references (the &…; syntax) use Unicode codepoints.

Comment: Minor point, but as a rule, it's best to avoid numbered entities. For ellipsis, there's a `&hellip;` entity for this purpose. It makes it easier to understand from the source what the intended output is, and eliminates any issue where the numbered entity means something else in a different encoding.

Answer (score 0):

echo htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");

Use this

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding explanation or documentation reference.